# How can I change a single box in a vaulted ceiling so that it can accommodate a double fixture?

Tags: ceiling

Previously, the vaulted ceiling did not have an electrical box.  My contractor made a level box (think letter "A") and it looks great.  It's all dry walled, etc.  The problem is, the light fixture has two rods and the plate is too wide for the surface he built.  Do you have any creative ideas as to how we can accommodate my light fixture without a total re-do??  HELP!
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[image: Box built by contractor]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would consider floating the double baseplate down far enough to gain the width you need. I'd add a box extender that's just enough to get it clear of the ceiling.

The baseplate will be floated a bit, but in my experience this doesn't detract from the appearance assuming that you don't have a level vantage point nearby.

Comment: Thank you so much.  He actually did expand the box and it worked great.  I'll try to add a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice of

- Modify more of the ceiling to build a bigger level spot with a larger box, or
- Use a different light fixture.

Maybe you (or someone) could modify the light fixture to not need that huge mounting plate.

Comment: Thank you.  The contractor was hoping not to have to modify it and I do not want to change the fixture.  I was hoping there was something creative we could do that met us both part way!!  lol